# how to fix the exception Unable to start activity ComponentInfo in android

Tags: android

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(1844): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chatr/com.example.chatr.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2351)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.chatr.MainActivity.SendMessage(MainActivity.java:68)
    at com.example.chatr.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1150)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315)
    ... 11 more
```

**Java Code :**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    HubConnection conn;
    HubProxy proxy;
    EditText edittext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //

     TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.setIdEditText);
            new a().execute();
            microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.Logger logger = new microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.Logger() {

                @Override
                public void log(String message, LogLevel level) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            };
            conn = new HubConnection("http://www.signalr.lociiapp.com/",
                    "userId=" + 5, true, logger);
            proxy = conn.createHubProxy("ChatHub");

            conn.start().done(new Action<Void>() {

                @Override
                public void run(Void obj) throws Exception {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            edittext.setText("Conected");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            SendMessage(5, 4, "Hello");
        }

        class a extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                SendMessage(5, 4, "Hello");
                return null;
            }

        }

        public void SendMessage(int id, int toid, String message) {

            proxy.invoke("SendMessage", new ReceiveObject(id, toid, message)).done(
                    new Action<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void run(Void obj) throws Exception {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
```

This is my code am getting exception which i have Print there even i have start service in thread please check  my code where am doing wrong am getting exception at line number 68 and 27 :

`new a().execute();` and    `proxy.invoke("SendMessage", new ReceiveObject(id, toid, message)).done(`  please help me

Comment: you are getting null pointer exception bcox proxy variable is null... reason behind this is you are calling SendMessage() method via asynkTask() before defining value to proxy... in OnCreate()... first define value to proxy variable and then call SendMessage() function

Answer (score 0):

proxy would be null at that point(line 68) as you are initializing it below and calling your asynctask before that.

```
    public void SendMessage(int id, int toid, String message) {
        //proxy will be null as it is initialized below in onCreate()
        proxy.invoke("SendMessage", new ReceiveObject(id, toid, message)).done(
                new Action<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void run(Void obj) throws Exception {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {

                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
    }
```

Move `new a().execute();` below every initializations or in your case below

`proxy =  conn.createHubProxy("ChatHub");`

Comment: Have u worked on Signal R problem is coming code is running but not getting value